# Unmarshal with changing JSON attribute

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a JSON object whose details can contain different types of JSON objects, the rest of the JSON remains the same, in such a case how can I have a single struct in Golang to handle both types of JSON

**JSON 1:**

```
{
   "field1":"",
   "field2":"",
   "field3":"",
   "field4":"",
   "field5":"",
   "field6":"",
   "field7":"",
   "details":{
      "detail1":"",
      "detail2":[
         {
            "arr1":"",
            "arr2":{
               "id":"",
               "name":""
            },
            "list":[
               {
                  "id":"",
                  "version":1,
                  "name":""
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "user":{
      "id":"",
      "name":""
   }
}
```

**JSON 2:**

```
{
   "field1":"",
   "field2":"",
   "field3":"",
   "field4":"",
   "field5":"",
   "field6":"",
   "field7":"",
   "details":{
      "anotherdetail1":"",
      "anotherdetail2":[
         {
            "arr7":"",
            "arr8":{
               "id":"",
               "name":""
            },
            "arr10":{

            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "user":{
      "id":"",
      "name":""
   }
}
```

My goal is to use a single struct for both these JSON objects. In a language like Java I would create a Parent Class which resembles details in a generic way and have 2 child classes to resemble the type of details that vary and during runtime I would create an object of a child type and assign it to the Parent. I am unsure how this is done in Go.

Comment: Either you make two `struct`s or you make `details` a `map[string]interface{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure you can have a single struct unless you are ok with a string interface map, but You can prevent the *details* from being decoded by setting them as a `json.RawMessage` type int he struct. You can then decode the unknown-typed json data by attempting to decode it into one type, if that returns an error then you try with the next type.

Here is some code, that should give you a better idea to what I am talking about.

https://play.golang.org/p/06owmiJXNaO

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

const json1 = `{"name": "foo", "details":[1, 2, 3]}`
const json2 = `{"name": "foo", "details":{"a": [1, 2, 3]}}`

type data struct {
    Name    string          `json:"name"`
    Details json.RawMessage `json:"details"`
}

type detailsone []int

type detailstwo struct {
    A []int `json:"a"`
}

func main() {
    var d1, d2 data
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json1), &d1)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json2), &d2)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d1)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", d2)

    var err error
    var b1 detailsone
    var b2 detailstwo

    // json1
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(d1.Details), &b1)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("d1 is an []int: %+v\n", b1)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(d1.Details), &b2)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("d1 is an detailstwo struct: %+v\n", b2)
    }

    // json2
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(d2.Details), &b1)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("d2 is an []int: %+v\n", b1)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(d2.Details), &b2)
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("d2 is an detailstwo struct: %+v\n", b2)
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a great answer, it does not seem to foot the desired outcome, as there is no dynamic naming. This will have to be done in a `map`

Answer (score 0):

```
type Base struct {
    Data map[string]interface{}

    Details struct {
        *D1
        *D2
    } `json:"details"
}

type D1 struct {
    Detail1 string
    Detail2 string
}

type D2 struct {
    AnotherDetail1 string
    AnotherDetail2 string
}
```

you can find filled struct by comparing them with `nil`

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that OP would have to define every possible field, and that does not seem to be the desired effect.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: yeah that looks better, but then at that point, you would only need the `Base` struct, and`Data` within it because essentially, you'd be pushing into `Data`, which you could give an inheritance feel to if attached a func to `Base` accepting a `string` for key and `interface{}` for value

Comment: didn't get what youre saying at all :|